# If $\zeta (s)=0$ with $\Im (s)>0$ in critical strip, does exist a real positive number $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\Im (s) \geq y$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Let $s$ be a zero of $\zeta$ Riemann zeta function  in critical strip with $\Im (s)>0$.

My question is: does it exist a real positive number $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\Im (s) \geq y$

Thanks.

Comment: $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ is entire and has no zeros on $[0,1]$ thus there is a rectangle $[0,1]+i[-t,t]$ where it has no zeros. The largest $t$ is $14.1347251417346937904572519835625..$. Is it what you are asking ?

Comment: @reuns thanks, it is just i was looking for